# Существует ли слово «перевыставлять»?

Tags: словообразование

День добрый! Вопрос в том, может ли существовать слово *перевыставлять?*

Могу ли я его вписать в договор или правильно заменить на другое?

Касаемо контекста:

*п. 3.5. Покупатель не имеет права перевыставлять спецификацию...*

Comment: Насчёт «правильно заменить на другое»: необходимы пояснения или контекст, хотя бы — что собираетесь выставлять?

Comment: У меня скорее вопрос возник из-за спора с коллегой. Он утверждает что слово "перевыставлять" существует в русском языке и его можно использовать в договоре. Я же хочу заменить. Далее уже дело принципа: существует такое слово или нет.
Касаемо контекста: 
п. 3.5. Покупатель не имеет права перевыставлять спецификацию......

Comment: Что это слово должно означать в контексте договора?

Comment: суть такова, что Покупатель не может заново выставить спецификацию, если она уже выставлена. Не может внести в неё изменения.... Но прошу прочитать выше мой коммент: мне важно есть ли такое слово в русском языке как "перевыставлять"

Answer (score 1):

В орфографическом словаре есть слово [перевыставить](http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/perevistavit/?q=532&n=163609).
В универсальном англо-русском словаре — понятие [перевыставлять затраты](https://translate.academic.ru/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B/en/ru/).

На *Грамоте.ру* в одном из вопросов есть такое предложение (без поправок):
*Законодательство о налогах и сборах не предусматривает такого процессуального действия, как **перевыставление** налоговым органом ранее выставленных инкассовых поручений путем направления в банк новых.*

В статье "[Расчеты с арендаторами по коммунальным услугам](http://www.reghelp.ru/article/rascheti_s_arendatorami_po.shtml)" (автор — И. Зернова, эксперт журнала «Автономные учреждения») разъясняется:
*Арендодатель также не вправе и **перевыставлять** счета-фактуры арендатору, поскольку в данном случае не является посредником между арендатором и поставщиком услуг...*

Довольно часто используется словосочетание *перевыставляемые услуги.*

[Как правильно перевыставляются счета?](https://vesbiz.ru/buxuchet/perevystavit-schet.html)